# KiCad: Ground plane won't connect to pads

Tags: kicad, ground-plane, pad

I am currently running into a problem in KiCad where the ground plane won't connect to some pads.

KiCad even tells me to connect them but doesn't seem to make the connection automatically.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the settings on the zone and the pads?

Comment: they need the same signal definition just any other wire to pad.

Comment: and/or when you run the rules check part of that is it computes the ground plane connections...

Comment: Things to check for: thermals (for the ground polygon, for the pads); any keepout zone in pcb or footprint? Overlapping pads in the footprint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked the settings of the plane and realized that pad connections were turned off. I placed another pad and KiCad turned connections on automatically. It was just a dumb mistake on my part; I thought they were enabled by default.

Thanks for the comments as they made me double-check the settings.

Comment: what settings have you changed? where they are?

Comment: If you look at the copper zone properties (click on the plane and press `e`) you will see a Pad Connections: drop down under Electrical Properties. You can pick Solid, Thermals, None, etc